# How to normalize PIL image between -1 and 1 in pytorch for transforms.Compose?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

So I have been trying to find a way to normalize some PIL image pixel values between -1 and 1. I searched through documentation and didn't find solution. Only normalization in documentation is `transforms.Normalize` which normalizes with mean and std. So I am stuck on how to do it. This is my code:

```
train_transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
        transforms.Resize(40),
        transforms.RandomCrop(32),
        # Normalize(-1, 1)  # Something like that
])
```

How can I normalize tensor between 2 numbers? For example:

```
[[1,2,3]
[3,2,1]]
```

Between -1 and 1

```
[[-1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, -1]]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5)
    transforms.Resize(40),
    transforms.RandomCrop(32),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), std=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
```

- ToTensor will scale image pixels from [0,255] to [0,1] values
- Normalize will first subtract the **mean** so [0,1] values will transform to range [-0.5,0.5], and then will divide with **std** and [-0.5,0.5] will reach [-1,1] range

Comment: @ just a note `transforms.Resize(40),` is not recommeded uses `transforms.Resize((40,40)),` instead , transforms.Resize(IMAGE_SIZE) resizes image PROPORTIONALY.  if you use celebrity dataset image (3, 178, 218) is resized to (3, 72, 64) by transforms.Resize(IMAGE_SIZE). 
also, we can write code directly like this
`transforms.Normalize([0.5 for _ in range(CHANNELS_NUM)],[0.5 for _ in range(CHANNELS_NUM)]),` shortcut